# Why does fork() result in duplicated output?

Tags: c++, linux, fork

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << 1;
    fork();
    exit(0);
}
```

The `fork` is located after streaming into `cout`, but this code prints 11.
Why? And why does the code only print 1 if `std::endl` is added to `cout`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    fork();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Buffers get flushed twice, in two processes. Man, that must be annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ objects do not play well with forking. Basically, the object is effectively copy-constructed without copy-constructing it, and this circumvents a lot of protection built by C++.

Comment: I can only imagine the havoc a `fork()` would wreak on standard containers. Just don't do this.

Comment: The duplicate was presented to you while you were writing your question. Please pay attention!

Comment: That's how `fork()` works and it can be very useful behavior. It's vital to setting up pipes for IPC. 

I don't see how it would wreak havoc on standard containers. After the `fork()` you have 2 separate processes which have identical memory images in separate memory spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's caused by stream buffering. Inserting `std::endl` into the stream causes it to be flushed, so when you fork, the stream buffer is empty. When you don't insert `std::endl`, the stream doesn't get flushed until program exit. `fork()` causes the output stream to be duplicated, including unflushed contents. After the `fork()` there are 2 processes with unflushed output buffers containing the '1'. They each exit, flushing their buffers and you see "11".